# ¿Existe async en php?

Tags: php, guzzle

Hola buenas tardes a todos, estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde debo conectarme a la API de ovh y obtener las ip que están siendo atacadas o recibieron spam

```
foreach($list as $i => $value){
$antihack = $ovh->get("/ip/{$value['ip']}/antihack");
$pishing = $ovh->get("/ip/{$value['ip']}/phishing");
$mitigacion = $ovh->get("/ip/{$value['ip']}/mitigation");
}
```

pero en php me envia este error `Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\services_ovh\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php`

¿hay alguna forma de usar la función async en php? saludos a todos

Comment: y porque no aumentas el tiempo de timeout si prevees que eso va a demorar mucho?

Comment: hola, lo intente pero la verdad no lo veo recomendable depender del tiempo

Comment: Entonces la unica que se me ocurre es que hagas las peticiones con curl, usando curl_multi_init: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-multi-init.php

Comment: Enterado gracias lo probaré :)

Comment: Hola buen día me funciono gracias :) segui este ejemplo **https://webkul.com/blog/simultaneous-curl-requests-in-php/**

Answer (score 0):

Veo varias soluciones a tu problema

**Solucion 1**

La mas facil :  aumentar el tiempo de ejecicion de los `scripts` de `php` esto lo logras escribiendo la siguiente linea de codigo al inicio del documento

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
//aqui el resto de tu codigo

?>
```

**Desventajas** : Debes esperar a que la solicitud termine, es decir:  la pestaña del navegador estara en blanco hasta que el `API` de `ovh`  termine de enviarte las respuestas.

**Soluicion 2**

Liberar el hilo principal de ejecucion de php. Esto lo logras enviado  a consola la ejecucion de dicho script.

```
#Direccion del documento a ejecutar
$direccion = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ."/consultas_api/consulta.php";

#Detectamos el sistema operativo del servidor  (WIN o LIN)
$sistema = strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3));

if($sistema == "LIN"){
  exec("php ".$direccion. " parametro1=".$parametro1. " parametro2=".$parametro2. " > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
}
   
if($sistema == "WIN"){
 pclose(popen("start /B php ".$direccion. " parametro1=".$parametro1. " parametro2=".$parametro2 , "r"));
}
```

**Importante**
En el documento que se ejecuta, `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] == ''` por lo que deberas  utilizar rutas absolutas  o `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]= "/var/www/vhosts/tusistema.com";`

**Desventajas**
Para depurar el script que se ejecuta  tendras que trazar log ya que no tendras salida de errores en pantalla

No sabaras cuando termine de ejecutar el `script de php` , por lo que tendras que enviar un email o manejar el estado via base de datos

**Solucion 3**

Crea un cron job esto  es parecido a la solucion 2 y tiene las mismas desventajas. pero puedes ejecutarlo cada cierto tiempo.

Comment: Hola buen dia, me funciono más el **curl_multi** aunque tomare en cuenta su solución gracias :)